# "The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?"

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

I'm on an ec2 instance trying to get my cluster created. I have kubectl already installed and here are my services and workloads yaml files

services.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: stockapi-webapp

spec:
  selector:
    app: stockapi

  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80

  type: LoadBalancer
```

workloads.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: stockapi
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: stockapi
  replicas: 1
  template: # template for the pods
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: stockapi
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: stock-api
        image: public.ecr.aws/u1c1h9j4/stock-api:latest
```

When I try to run

```
kubectl apply -f workloads.yaml
```

I get this as an error

```
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

I also tried changing the port in my services.yaml to 8080 and that didn't fix it either

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This error comes when you don't have `~/.kube/config` file present or configured correctly on the client / where you run the `kubectl` command.

kubectl reads the clusterinfo and which port to connect to from the  `~/.kube/config` file.

if you are using eks here's how you can create `config` file
[aws eks create kubeconfig file](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/create-kubeconfig.html)

Comment: The path to the kube config file can be read/set via the variable `$KUBECONFIG` FWIW.

Comment: what about azure?

Comment: If someone using minikube make sure to start minikube using this command `minikube start`

Answer (score 4):

In my case I had a problem with a certificate authority. Found out that by checking the kubectl config

```
kubectl config view
```

The clusters part was null, instead of having something similar to

```
- cluster:
certificate-authority-data: DATA+OMITTED
server: https://kubernetes.docker.internal:6443
  name: docker-desktop
```

It was not parsed because of time differences between my machine and a server (several seconds was enough).

Running

```
sudo apt-get install ntp
sudo apt-get install ntpdate
sudo ntpdate ntp.ubuntu.com
```

Had solved the issue.

Comment: Although my problem differed, `kubectl config view` is an excellent debugging step.

Answer (score 3):

Encountered the exact error in my cluster when I executed the "kubectl get nodes" command.

## The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?

I ran the following command in master node and it fixed the error.

apt-get update && apt-get install -y apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl software-properties-common

curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | apt-key add -

add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal stable"

apt-get update && apt-get install -y containerd.io

## Configure containerd

mkdir -p /etc/containerd

containerd config default > /etc/containerd/config.toml

systemctl restart containerd

Answer (score 0):

I was following the instructions on [aws](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/install-kubectl.html)

With me, I was on a Mac. I had docker desktop installed. This seemed to include kubectl in homebrew

I traced it down to a link in `usr/local/bin` and renamed it to `kubectl-old`

Then I reinstalled kubectl, put it on my path and everything worked.

I know this is very specific to my case, but may help others.

Comment: That's exactly what i did on my Mac too, or you can just open Docker GUI on Mac or Window before you use `kubectl`. You could check API server with `docker ps | grep kube-apiserver`

Answer (score 0):

ERROR:
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?

In my case, issue was fixed by exporting the KUBECONFIG

*export KUBECONFIG=/home/.kube/kubeconfig*

Answer (score -1):

I found how to solve this question. Run the below commands

1.sudo -i
2.swapoff -a
3.exit
4.strace -eopenat kubectl version

and you can type kubectl get nodes again.

Cheers !

Answer (score -1):

I got the same error and after switching from root user to regular user (ubuntu, etc...) my problem was fixed.